# javascript setting select element options using getElementsById

Tags: javascript

I have a form in which i use javascript to set the select element options depending on type of property (house, flat, etc). it is working now when I am accessing the list using the document.myForm.priceSelect.options.

I want to access it by id rather than name. Because I want to set the name also along with the options so that when the form is submitted, the name of the list will determine which function to execute. Some code to illustrate:

```
 if(prop_type == 'flat') {
            document.getElementById('priceRange').setAttribute('name', 'flatRange');
            .....
```

Now here I am changing the name of the select list called priceRange. How can I also change the options using the id instead of the name like shown below:

```
document.searchForm.priceRange.options[1]=new Option("10000 - 20000", "10000 - 20000");
```

Thank you in advance...

UPDATE:

After change: (not working)

```
 if(prop_type == 'flat') {
            document.getElementById('priceRange').setAttribute('name', 'flatRange');
            document.getElementById('priceRange').options.length=0;
            document.getElementById('priceRange').options[0]=new Option("", "");
            document.getElementById('priceRange').options[1]=new Option("10000 - 20000", "10000 - 20000");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use

```
document.getElementById(yourId).options[1]=new Option("10000 - 20000", "10000 - 20000");
```

Comment: Didn't work. I updated the code above to show changes. Now the list just doesn't display anything.

Answer (score 0):

dystroy's method should work - see this [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/yQRPr/)

An alternative is to create a wrapper method for option creation, such as this:

```
function createOption(objSelect, optText, optValue){
  var objOption = document.createElement("option");
  objOption.text = optText;
  objOption.value = optValue;

  if(document.all && !window.opera){
    objSelect.add(objOption);
  }
  else
  {
    objSelect.add(objOption, null);
  };
}
```

Then you can add options to the select:

```
var priceRange=document.getElementById('priceRange');
createOption(priceRange, "10000 - 20000", "lowball");
```

Fiddle for the wrapper method [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mG9qv/2/)